# cavity scaling around part features

Tags: solidworks

I'm trying to add a cavity in part A using part B in an assembly. I'd like to expand the cavity uniformly away from the B around each feature. Instead, the cavity seems to be expanding from the center.

All of the "scale about" options produce similar results. The origin of part A and B are at their centers.

[image: cavity]

Edit:
From the comments, it looks like offset is what I should be looking at. I created an offset surface but I'm not sure how to trim or cut it from the part.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for offset surface, rather than scale? That it you need to split into 4 bodies and then merge after scaling individually about their centre points.

Comment: Offsetting your surfaces should do the trick.  What you are doing now is scaling the whole part- not what you want.